# How to generate random numbers from different intervals that add up to a fixed sum in excel?

Tags: excel, algorithm, random, sum, intervals

I need to generate 13 numbers from 13 different intervals which will add up to 1360. In the chart below, "index" means the index of the 13 different numbers. Mean means the mean (average) of the intervals. The range will be plus or minus 15% of the mean as shown below. **I will prefer to have the random numbers generated based on the normal distribution with N(mean, 7.5% of mean).** I take it back. No normal distribution. Please use +- 15% as hard limits of the intervals.

It will be great if anyone could figure out how to do it in excel. Algorithms will be appreciated as well.

```
Index      mean    15%     low    high

  A        288     43      245    331
  B        50      8       43     58
  C        338     51      287    389
  D        50      8       43     58
  E        16      2       14     18
  F        66      10      56     76
  G        118     18      100    136
  H        17      3       14     20
  I        91      14      77     105
  J        26      4       22     30
  K        117     18      99     135
  L        165     25      140    190
  M        18      3       15     21
```

Comment: A normal distribution does not set hard min/max limits on values.

Comment: Yep I understand. I provided the normal distribution I prefer to use N(mean, 7.5% of mean). I was trying to say that if it's not possible to use normal distribution, I'm open to any other random number generating algorithms as long as the numbers will be in those intervals and add up to 1345. Thanks!

Comment: Are the 13 mean values fixed, or are they also somehow random?

Comment: They are fixed!

Comment: Is it intended that the sum of the means is 1360 and the desired sum is 1354, which means that the expected value for each of the random values will be slightly below the mean?

Comment: Sorry I didn't convert the problem completely. It should be 1360 instead of 1354. I will edit my question.

Comment: Should the random values be integers or can they have a fractional part?

Comment: Integers only please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sort the table by increasing mean:

[image]

and use a column for a helper value (column H above).

The idea is to maintain -- while going to the next row -- the current deviation from a perfect aim for the final target. Perfect would mean that every random value coincides with the mean for that row. If a value is 2 less than the mean, then that 2 will appear in the H column for the next row. The random number generated for that next row will then not aim for the given mean, but for 2 less than the mean. The range for the random number will appropriately be reduced so that the low/high values will never be crossed.

By first sorting the rows, we can be sure that this corrected mean will always fall within the next row's low/high range, and so it will always be possible to generate an acceptable random number there.

The final value will be calculated differently: it will be the remainder that is needed to achieve the target sum. For the same reason as above, this value is guaranteed to be within the low/high range.

The formulas used are as follows:

```
   |                       F                          |              H
 --+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------
 2 | =RANDBETWEEN(D2, E2)                             |
 3 | =RANDBETWEEN(B3+H3-C3+ABS(H3), B3+H3+C3-ABS(H3)) | =SUM($B$2:$B2)-SUM($F$2:$F2)
 4 |      (copy above formula)                        | (copy above formula)
...|              ...                                 |         ...
13 |      (copy above formula)                        | (copy above formula)
14 | =SUM($B$2:$B14)-SUM($F$2:$F13)                   |
```

In theory the rows do not *need* to be sorted first, but then the formulas cannot be copied down like above, but must reference the correct rows. That would make it quite complicated.

If it is absolutely necessary that the rows are presented in order of the Index column (A, B, C...), then use another sheet to do the above. Then in the main sheet read the value into the F column with a VLOOKUP from the other sheet. So in F2 you would have:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, OtherSheet!$A$2:$F$14, 6, 0)
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand the concept. I have a couple of concerns though.

Comment: First, for every number after the first one, you use an adjusted interval. And it's basically (low+2*adjustment, high) or (low, high - 2*adjustment). However, if the interval itself is less than 2*adjustment, you will have errors. Second, it is probably very unlikely, but the final number as SUM($B$2:$B14)-SUM($F$2:$F13)  could still be out of its range. I think it's close! Thanks!

Comment: This is why it is required to sort by the mean, which means the table will be sorted by interval size, and so it will not be possible to get out of range.

Comment: Right! Keep forgetting about the sort. Okay. I will go ahead and try it in excel and observe the performance. Wandering how random it will be. Will let you know. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How did it go? Any conclusions?

Comment: Yes! The randomness is good. Thank you so much! I could go with it but it will be ideal if I could meet another constrain. As you probably noticed, mean A + mean B = mean C, mean D + mean E = mean F, and mean I + mean J = mean K. Is there a way that we can keep these equations for the random numbers generated?

Comment: That extra constraint cannot be met with this method: you would lose the guarantee that a random number would stay within the allowable range. As you did not mention this constraint in your question, I think you would need to ask it as a new question. I will think about that challenge, but I think it needs a different approach.

Comment: I think for these 3 pairs, we can have 2 numbers as random and have the 3rd number as a calculation result based on the first 2. I think the concept will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Get the random number like this

```
num = Int ((300 - 200 + 1) * Rnd + 200) //between 200 and 300
```

[Click here for more information](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php)

and the random number need to be the total sum minus the sum that you already got and the last one will be that left.

for example: (if we have 4 numbers sum up to 100)

```
A is a random number between 0 to 100 //lets say 42
then B is a random number between 0 to (100-42) => 0 to 78 //lets say 18
then C is a random number between 0 to (100-42-18) => 0 to 40 //lets say 25
then, in the end D is 100-42-18-25 => D is 15

*100-42-18-25 is the same as 100-Sum(A,B,C)
```

Comment: Ummmm but each of my random numbers will need to be in its own interval? I couldn't see how your algorithm take care of this part. It's very likely that my 13th number, which should be in the interval of (15,21), has to fill the gap which is greater than 21. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: you can do it with a loop and an array with 13 places in it, every time you put another number in its place (`for i =0 to 13`) and have an Integer of the left over (like in my example - in run i = 2 the left over integer will be 40.

Comment: I don't think I understand how this approach will take care of the issue. Would you please be more specific?

Comment: This approach will make sure that the sum of the numbers you get are 1360 not more and not less.

Comment: Yeah, the fixed sum part is taken care of. However, each of my random numbers should be in its own specific interval as described in the problem statement.

Comment: Can you please give a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is my example generate random number based on low and high.

The formula in `column F` is just a `RANDBETWEEN`:

```
=RANDBETWEEN($D2,$E2)
```

Then you can get the result always equal to 1360 with the formula below for `column G`:

```
=F2/SUM($F$2:$F$14)*1360
```

So `cell G15` will always be 1360 which is the sum of all those 13 intervals.

Comment: This will not guarantee that the result values will stay within low-high range.

Comment: I like it! It's a brilliant answer thank you! I didn't know this formula. Does it uniformly generate the random numbers? If no body come up with anything else which could have the random numbers have a higher probability to be generated around the mean, I will go with it!

Comment: Hmmm, @trincot is correct.  I didn't notice that sometimes there will be some noises generated.  I will need to play around it more...

Comment: @Viola, the formula is very close but can't guarantee all the results will fall within the low-high range.  I will need more time or maybe someone can come up a better way for it.

Comment: @Viola, I found something online that may help you (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/242354-generating-set-random-numbers-total-set-value.html).  Not so easy and it made my head hurts on a Friday evening.  I will try again during the weekend or next week.

Comment: Right, I see it now. If you bring it up or down using a ratio, it could go outside of the range. Thanks to both of you! I will look into the link.@ian0411